# Best way to provide commit information that should be deployed to AWS Codepipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, cd

Since the code pipeline does not support git tag-based triggers natively, what's the best way to control what commit should be deployed using code pipeline/code build, in case we do not want to deploy the head of the branch?

Comment: If you don't want to deploy the head, you can create a long-live "deployable" branch and use it as the source for CodePipeline.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a article about ["Customizing triggers for AWS CodePipeline with AWS Lambda and Amazon CloudWatch Events"](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/adding-custom-logic-to-aws-codepipeline-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-cloudwatch-events/). Hopefully, it can help you.

However, the solution in the article maybe a little complex.

If your source code is stored in a GitHub or Bitbucket repository. You may try to create a custom webhook with some filters
as you like, please refer to this [link](https://www.transposit.com/docs/integrations/connectors/aws-codebuild-documentation/#create_webhook) for details about creating webhook.